# "ed form + noun" vs "noun + ed form"

Tags: subordinate-clauses, modifiers

Are the following sentence grammatically correct and semantically identical?

- The surveyed people were not congruous.
- The people surveyed were not congruous.
- The people whom surveyed were not congruous.
- The people that surveyed were not congruous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are essentially the same:

> The (surveyed) people were not congruous.
>   The people (who were surveyed) were not congruous.

I think you would use *who* with people, but *that* could be OK similar to your fourth example:

> The books (that were sold) were expensive.

Using *whom* is incorrect because there is no objective case.

Answer (score 0):

The first two seem more natural. However, 'surveyed' in the first is an adjective, and in second, it's a verb. Semantically, they are identical and convey the same message.

The third seems improper.

The fourth one brings in a doubt that what did 'people survey'? There, anyone would expect 'survey' to be a transitive verb requiring a direct object.

Say--

> The people that surveyed *a document* were not happy with the wordings in it!